# Unable to open third party `DialogFragment` which uses Android Support Library while I am using AndroidX

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I am getting the below error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.co.XXX.XXX, PID: 22650
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
```

I am using the code as below in my app

```
private void openCouponsListController() {
    CouponsDialogFragment couponsDialogFragment = CouponsDialogFragment.newInstanceForList(CategoryId.FLIGHTS);
    couponsDialogFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(), CouponsDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
}
```

The `CouponsDialogFragment` uses support libraries while my app is in AndroidX. I am able to use Activity from the library but not able to figure out what is the issue with this fragment. The developer of the library has provided an Activity that shows this dialog in onCreate; It works but I am not able to open the dialog from my app.

The fragment is importing following libraries

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

The layout file is as shown below

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorToolbarBg"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/NuToolbarTheme"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <!--todo :- need to verify we need this or not-->
    <!--app:titleTextAppearance="@style/NuToolbarTitleTextAppearance"-->

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Already set the following in `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Due to the above changes, the layout files and fragment is using AndroidX. In the original library it is support library.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: can you please post the imports which is used for CouponsDialogFragment, also in th activity file

Comment: @MikeM. Added the stack trace.

Comment: which library??

Comment: @PembaTamang, It is closed library being used between the two organisation.

Comment: I import the library as a module and use the `migrate to anroidx` on the classes and see

Comment: I can use all the activity in the library. The problem is only with the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) . Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead. The tool lets you migrate an individual library directly, instead of using the Android gradle plugin bundled with Android Studio.

To enable it, add `android.enableJetifier=true` to your gradle.properties.

Comment: Already done and that allowed me to use Activities from that library but unable to open dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorToolbarBg"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:elevation="0dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/NuToolbarTheme"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!--todo :- need to verify we need this or not-->
<!--app:titleTextAppearance="@style/NuToolbarTitleTextAppearance"-->

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

You're using androidx components in the XML, but the fragment which you're using old support libraries which is causing the issue.

**First set up your project with all the third-party libraries, after building successfully migrate the project to androidx**

> `android.enableJetifier: When set to true`, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

Comment: Fragment is also using AndroidX. There are two sets of import/xml. One after adding to my app and one from the original library.

Comment: When did you migrate your project  to androidx, before adding the library of after that @Prashant

Comment: Before adding the library.

Comment: @Prashant that's not the way to do, first set up your project with all the third-party libraries, after building successfully migrate the project to androidx

Comment: What if we need to add another third party library after that?

Comment: chech for any updated library with androidx then @Prashant